# Python CSSSelect long selectors not working?

Tags: python, html, css, css-selectors

I'm having some problems with cssselect.
Selectors like these don't work: `#foo div.bar div div.baz p`
But selecting `#foo`, then `div.bar` on the result of the first query and so on works.

I suppose I could split the selector at each space and implement it as a recursive function, but that would limit the available css selectors by removing (or forcing me to reimplement) `a+b`, `a>b`, `a,b` and so on.

I really want to use css selectors when parsing html (instead of xpath for example), since I (we) know them well already and because they can be reused in javascript/css.

Is there something I'm missing? Any better library?